# erlang ssh_sftp start_channel function call is getting failed

Tags: erlang, port, sftp, distributed

We have a distributed system system built on **erlang** with one server node and hundreds of client nodes(the systems are distributed over the intra-net). We have a requirement that all the client nodes will connect to the server node and try to download some file(mostly the same file will be accessed by all client nodes) **simultaneously** by using sftp.  The steps we follow for downloading the file is:

1. Establish ssh sftp connection between the server node and client node using function call as below:

   `ssh_sftp:start_channel/2` .
2. Then reads the file by doing function call as below:

   `ssh_sftp:read_file/2`

The problem what we are facing is that when the number of clients are more then it is observed that few client nodes are failing to establish connection between server node. i.e. the `ssh_sftp:start_channel/2` function call is failing.

Can somebody please explain me;

1. Is there any limitation for the number of sftp session what we can establish in a single system ?
2. What are the possible reason because of which the connection request fails ?
3. Is there anything wrong we are doing in this approach ?
4. Is there any better solution by which we can guarantee that all client nodes will be able to connect to server and will be able to download the file.

Observation: We tried to connect 25 client nodes to the server; during the first try only 2 nodes failed to connect and on the second try 5 nodes failed to connect. Why this random behavior ?.

Comment: What is actually `ssh_sftp:start_channel/2` returning?

Answer (score 0):

I think I can answer some question below (fix me if I wrong):

1. Erlang is really strong when you use this concurrent, so your issue here is power of your physical hardware (server).
2. I don't really know what the issue in your project but my project about telecom can easy handle a thousand call which 2 process handle each call. 1 process is the master process handle the session (connection) and each other watching and handle error master process, so that be can NOT failed the connection